# Getting initial null value from servlet response

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

Here is my javascript code where i have called a servlet by using ajax..

```
        eSelect.onchange = function() {

        var sel=eSelect.options[eSelect.selectedIndex].value;
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "methodcall",
        data: {"frameID": sel},
        success: function(result) {


            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert("Data not found");
            }

    });

   <%  ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
       ArrayList per=new ArrayList();
       al = (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("servletName");
       per=(ArrayList)request.getAttribute("Percentage");
       System.out.println(al); %>}
```

and here is my servlet response ..

```
     request.setAttribute("servletName", city_name);
     request.setAttribute("Percentage", percentage);
     rd= request.getRequestDispatcher("statistics.jsp");
     rd.forward(request, response);
```

I am receiving the values but the first time when i run it , i get a null value . 
I am not familiar with ajax so i just used it to call the servlet . Please help . thanx in advance..

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in the server code to check if the values of `city_name` and `percentage` being sent back the first time are null or not? It could be an error in your servlet code.

Comment: i have checked it in the servlet , its returning the correct values .

Comment: i have checked it in the servlet , its returning the correct values .I feel that the null value is getting generated when the page is getting loaded the first time . Then when i change the <option>- <selection> i am getting my values..  Does the scriptlet code gets evaluated before the Javascript??

Comment: How are you invoking the request to your servlet: throught the ajax request only or by another way?

Comment: I am invoking it by ajax request only. But I am not using the success event of ajax for the response.

Comment: The values is only showing in sop in  scriptlet .. It gives a null value when i try to use alert in js.                                                                                                                                                                          alert('<%=al%>');